# Typeof Expressions (Number )

Tags: javascript

The following expressions give peculiar result in JavaScript.

```
typeof (5 + "7")   // Gives string
typeof (5 - "7")   // Gives number
```

How do I get the result of the first expression as a number type?

Is there any way to do that without explicitly converting 7 to a number?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do that without explicitly converting the string to a number, and that is by implicitly converting the string. You can for example use the `+` operator, which will cause an implicit conversion of the string to a number, as it can only be applied to a number:

```
typeof (5 + +"7")
```

That's not very readable code, though. You are better off with an explicit conversion:

```
typeof (5 + parseFloat("7"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this way parsing string to integer first. You can parse string implicitly with `+` or parse to integer with `parseInt`.

```
typeof (5 + +"7")
```

or

```
typeof (5 + parseInt("7"))
```

Comment: Note: The `+` operator doesn't parse the string as an integer, it causes an implicit conversion as a floating point number. `parseInt("7.9")` returns `7`, while `+"7.9"` returns `7.9`.

Comment: @Guffa thanks for giving information. Learned new thing today

Answer (score 0):

The plus sign in javascript adds numbers together, but it also concatenates strings, and when **one** of the values being added together is a string, the latter is done, regardless of what the other values are.

The minus sign subtracts, and you can't subtract a string from a string, so it's only meaning is to subtract numbers

So in other words

```
5 + "7" === "57" // string
5 + 7   === 12   // number
5 - "7" === -2   // number
```

so no, you'd have to convert the string to a number to be able to add it to another number

```
5 - ( parseInt("7", 10) ) === -2   // number
5 - ( +"7" ) === -2   // number
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you'd be able to so that **is** by converting the string to a number

```
typeof (5 + parseInt("7"))
```

N.b. that's if you are using the plus operator, multiply/divide/minus work differently and will convert the string type to a number (unless NaN)

Comment: The above expression is one of the ways. The other way is to use typeof(5 + + "7") as mentioned by Guffa